# Bootstrap 3.2 Col Margins

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have been hitting a area which I dont belive is coverd in the bootstrap documentation which is to add margins to col in bootstrap.

To fix this I used the following code but the issue is the centre box is always smaller then the outer two.

Does anyone have a fix to this? 
[image]

**HTML**

```
    <div class="row">
    <div  class="col-lg-4">
        <div id="lightBlueFix" class="marginBoxes noMarginLeft"> 
            <div class="clearBoth"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div id="lightGrey" class="marginBoxes"> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div id="lightYellow" class="marginBoxes noMarginRight"> 
        </div>
    </div>     
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.marginBoxes {
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
} 
.noMarginLeft{
    margin-left:0 !important;   
}
.noMarginRight{
    margin-right:0 !important;  

}
```

**[Live Preview](http://isca01.bigwavemedia.info/~activenorth/)** #

Comment: Get the source, open up `variables.less` and change the `@grid-gutter-width` variable

Comment: If you don't want to use `less` (as suggested by @Doctus), then go to http://getbootstrap.com/customize, change the `@grid-gutter-width` from 30px to your choice and download the files.

Comment: I have less, can you point me to the correct place?

Comment: @DavidG that's an idea! I forgot about that. If you are unsure what I was talking about Brent, then I would suggest you use the online customization tool as suggested. LESS is a CSS preprocessor that adds functions to CSS, Bootstrap is built with it.

Comment: Oh right, well look for `less/variables.less` then search for `grid-gutter-width`, change it and recompile.

Comment: If you have less and it's compiling your Bootstrap already, just open up the file as @Doctus mentioned and make the change. (PS how odd to find someone making a website about Northumberland - I'm from Blyth!)

Comment: @grid-gutter-width:         30px; is set, but my document is greyed out. Not sure if its my text editor or its commented out.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/eDmNuqfg

Comment: @grid-gutter-width will change the space between columns. By default, it's 30px. You can change this var to have the space you want - so you don't need to add custom css

Comment: but there is no spacing?

Comment: By space I mean the sum of margin-right and margin-left : by default you have a space of 30px wich means `margin-right: 15px` and `margin-left: 15px`. If you set `@grid-gutter-width: 40px` you will have `margin-right: 20px` and `margin-left: 20px`

Comment: http://pastebin.com/qq2KULVc

Comment: Thinking about this more, I'd probably leave the margins as they are now and make your 3-block-banner into it's own component.

Comment: Yeah might go down this root, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, I'd leave Bootstrap alone and make the boxes separate, possibly something along these lines:

```css
#lightBlueFix { background-color: blue; }
#lightGrey { background-color: grey; }
#lightYellow { background-color: yellow; }

.bannerBox {
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
    <div  class="col-lg-4">
     <div id="lightBlueFix" class="bannerBox"> 
            Blue
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div id="lightGrey" class="bannerBox"> 
            Grey
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div id="lightYellow" class="bannerBox"> 
            Yellow
        </div>
    </div>     
</div>
```